# Objective-C: Convert id to NSInteger

Tags: objective-c

I have a dictionary with an NSNumber in it and I'd like to convert it into NSInteger. Is the simplest/shortest way to do this is to typecast into NSNumber and then calling integerValue? Like so:

```
// newQuestion is an NSDictionary defined somewhere
NSInteger questionId = [(NSNumber *)[newQuestion objectForKey:@"question_id"] integerValue];
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can get rid of the cast if you want to make it shorter:

```
// newQuestion is an NSDictionary defined somewhere
NSInteger questionId = [[newQuestion objectForKey:@"question_id"] integerValue];
```

Since `objectForKey:` returns `id`, you can send it any known message and the compiler won't complain.

Comment: Thanks, @albertamg and @Dietrich. I upvoted both you guys, but chosen @albertamg as the right answer simply because he's first :)

Comment: Just to be clear, the compiler won't complain about sending any message to an `id`, instead if the object isn't really an object (a struct or primitive), or doesn't respond to that message, you'll get an exception at runtime (not at build).

Comment: @RyanR: Yes but... It is not safer to cast it to `NSNumber` if it's not a `NSNumber`. And it can not be a struct or primitive because `id` means it is an object (of unknown class).

Comment: I wasn't trying to encourage the poster to cast it to NSNumber, merely making sure they realize that treating everything as `id` moves 'does not respond to selector' errors from compile time to run time. If it was an NSRange boxed into an NSValue, calling `-intValue` on it would cause the exception at run time, which a lot of new developers have trouble with.

Comment: Would it not be more correct to use "integerForKey" instead of "objectForKey" and then converting the object to an integer value?

Comment: @Cedric `newQuestion` is a dictionary. Dictionaries don't have an `integerForKey` method. Are you thinking of `NSUserDefaults`?

Comment: Yes I was. Thanks for the correction and clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you don't need to cast.

```
NSInteger questionId = [[newQuestion objectForKey:@"question_id"] integerValue];
```

The cast doesn't actually do anything in this particular case.  If the item in your dictionary is not a `NSNumber` (e.g., it's `nil`), then `questionId` will be 0.

Comment: If it is `nil`, then `questionId` will be 0, but if it is an object of another class different from `NSNumber` that does not have a method called `integerValue`, it will crash.

Comment: @Bavarious The return value of `objectForKey:` is the value associated with the key (which can **not** be nil), or **nil** if no value is associated with the key.

Comment: @alb You’re right, of course. That’ll teach me to do more things in parallel than I’m capable of. :)

Comment: @albertamg: It won't crash if you send it a selector it doesn't recognize.  Try it.

Comment: @Dietrich: Yes, it throws a `NSInvalidArgumentException` exception ("unrecognized selector sent to instance") that will make the program crash if it is not catched.

Comment: Hm, I wouldn't call an exception a crash.  Especially since it will be caught be the outer loop.

Comment: @Dietrich Hmm, the behaviour is different in Mac OS X and iOS... In iOS it will crash. Anyway, exceptions should not be used for general flow-control nor to signify errors that the programmer could do nothing about. Exceptions are typically used for programmer error such as sending an unrecognized selector to an instance.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. That is the way to go.   The question, though, is why do you need to turn into an integer in the first place?  That may be avoidable.   Or not.

Comment: To save some memory since NSInteger is leaner than NSNumber? Or am I being paranoid and should just use NSNumber everywhere?

Comment: I usually prefer having a cleaner and easy-to-ready code, rather than optimizing the code by a few milliseconds. Also, remember that all these NSNumber<->NSUInteger conversions are done by the device's CPU

Comment: I don't see any indication that this question is about performance.  `NSNumber` is only useful in that you can put it in a container or hook it up to your UI.  You can't, e.g, pass `NSNumber` to `NSArray` `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: @aporat: What do you mean by "done by the device's CPU"?  All application code is run by the device's CPU, except stuff you do through OpenGL.

Comment: No, the question is not about performance. I know that NSInteger is going to save me some memory (albeit very small one and with a bit of CPU overhead tradeoff).

Comment: @Pixelfreak this won't save you any memory, because the `NSNumber` still exists (since it is strongly referenced by the dictionary).

Comment: @Dave The dictionary goes away after in the code. It's just a temporary container.